# Guidance on webscraping using Google Sheets

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get some data from a web page using import XML but it tells me "N/A Imported content is empty"

I've tried with a different query but is not working.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.shein.com/Floral-Lace-Halter-Teddy-Bodysuit-p-699186-cat-1862.html","//div[@class='opt-size j-sa-select-size j-opt-size']")
```

I want to be able to parse the different sizes of the clothing, that would be: XS, S, M, L, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Sheets does not support web scraping of JavaScript controlled elements. you can easily check it by disabling JS for a given site and only what's left visible can be scraped. in your case, that's nothing, unfortunately:

[image: 0]

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. Do you think I could use Google Apps Script (GAS) to get the information I want?

Comment: more likely you would solve it with vba in ms excel which is able to scrape JS as I heard